# Logon message still prompting to upgrade release after upgrading release

Tags: do-release-upgrade

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-143-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage


0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

New release '18.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.


Last login: Sat Mar 23 16:56:46 2019 from 108.39.82.222
:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

I'm a bit annoyed by this. Did it fail to upgrade somehow? It was 16.04 before.

Output of lsb_release -a as requested:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lsb_release -a` in the question.

Comment: Added lsb_release -a output

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Only difference is the message I'm receiving is: * Upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS by running:   sudo do-release-upgrade -p